# Generate file upload input for property with "DataType.Upload" attribute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following view model.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }

    public int VenueId { get; set; }
    public virtual Venue Venue { get; set; }
    .... // other properties
}
```

I'm following this page http://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/ to create image upload control. Here is the view code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Event", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

   <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VenueId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VenueId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VenueId)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUpload, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageUpload)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageUpload)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

However, it generates three text boxes instead of file upload input control? The following Html code.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="ImageUpload_ContentLength">ContentLength</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input name="ImageUpload.ContentLength" class="text-box single-line" id="ImageUpload_ContentLength" type="number" value="" data-val-required="The ContentLength field is required." data-val-number="The field ContentLength must be a number." data-val="true"> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ImageUpload.ContentLength"></span></div>
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="ImageUpload_ContentType">ContentType</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input name="ImageUpload.ContentType" class="text-box single-line" id="ImageUpload_ContentType" type="text" value=""> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ImageUpload.ContentType"></span></div>
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="ImageUpload_FileName">FileName</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input name="ImageUpload.FileName" class="text-box single-line" id="ImageUpload_FileName" type="text" value=""> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ImageUpload.FileName"></span></div>

    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ImageUpload"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your image control to this,

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImageUpload, new { type = "file", name = "Files" })
```

Answer (score 1):

How about getting rid of the HttpPostedFileBase from the model and adding it to the controller as a second parameter.

In your html, you would add:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

In your controller you would do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult thisController(Model myModel, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{ }
```

This should automatically catch any file you input.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 You making sure you're putting a file in to upload?

Comment: My bad. I changed the `name` and forgot to change the action parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I have another idea.
How about getting rid of the HttpPostedFileBase from the model and from the controller either ?

In your html, you would add:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("actionNameYouWriteToManupulate", "controllerYouWrite", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
   <input type="file" name="file" id="File1" />
   <input type="file" name="file" id="File2" />
   ...
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-info" />
 }
```

Add Files as many files you want, and in the controller :

```
var hfc = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
            {
                var hpf = hfc[i];
                if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                   //Do what you want with files 
                   //Handler pointed to file is hpf for example :
                   hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fullPathWithFileName));
                 }
            }
```

Hope to be usefull.