# Scaffold a FileUploader

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, file-upload

Is it possible to create a Model that when scaffolded will create a View that renders a HTML File Upload object?

For example design a model for uploading images that will scaffold the views to include the image uploader.

I have tried Models with he following properties but they rendered as text boxes with no upload option.

```
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [Display(Name = "Upload a File")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose file to upload.")]
    public string file { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Upload File 2")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose file to upload.")]
    public HttpPostedFile myfile { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not sure about scaffolding in this context, but does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772153/generate-file-upload-input-for-property-with-datatype-upload-attribute) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your HttpPostedFile, if you are using EditorFor(x => x.myfile) what it does is inspect the type the property specified in the expression and attempt to find a matching editor template for that type. This templates tell Razor what HTML it should generate for a property of the type the template implements. Razor has a couple of templates that you can override and they are not visible in the project, but HttpPostedFile is not one of them, that is why maybe you are seeing FileName, ContentType and ContentLength as the interface rendered for that HttpPostedFile.

Bellow is the implementation of that class HttpPostedFile

```
public abstract class HttpPostedFileBase {

        public virtual int ContentLength {
            get {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public virtual string ContentType {
            get {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public virtual string FileName {
            get {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public virtual Stream InputStream {
            get {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1702:CompoundWordsShouldBeCasedCorrectly", MessageId = "filename",
            Justification = "Matches HttpPostedFile class")]
        public virtual void SaveAs(string filename) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

Because one of those templates is not on of the defaults,Razor explores the class and tries to generate editor for each public property of the class.

If you specify a DataType over the property

```
[DataType(DataType.SELECTYOURTYPEHERE)]
```

Then you can override the templates on

**Views/Shared/EditorTemplates**, for example you can do this

```
[DataType(DataType.Upload)]
public HttpPostedFile myfile { get; set; }
```

and then create and Upload.cshtml on **Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Upload.cshtml**
with the html you want to display for the Upload.

Hope this helps